# Vector will not accept result (returns it as blank)

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
webpage <- "https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes"
heroes <- read_html(webpage) %>% 
  html_nodes("div.name") %>% 
  html_text()
heroes <- sapply(gsub(" ","-",heroes), tolower)
```

It pulls a list of names from this website. When I run this code, it correctly parses all the hero names as lowercase and with words separated by hyphens.

When I run this code:

```
cat(webpage,heroes[i],sep="/")
```

with i being the object from the vector that I want to return (I intend to use it in a `for` loop), it will correctly return the webpage as I expect. However, when I do

```
var <- cat(webpage,heroes[i],sep="/")
```

it tells me that `var` is null, and does not have a value. It also will not assign that value to anything in the `for` loop, either, presenting it as null.

I've also tried

```
var <- toString(cat(webpage,heroes[i],sep="/"))
```

but that didn't work either (same issue)

What am I missing here?

I'm running this all in https://rstudio.cloud, for context. Is it something with the environment? I would have thought this would be simple.

Comment: If you look at `?cat`, it says that `cat` doesn't return anything, it just prints directly to the console. You're thinking of `paste` or `paste0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to used `paste` instead of `cat`. The `cat`-function which is intended for printing whereas the `paste`-function is for concatenating strings:

```
var <- paste(webpage, heroes[i], sep="/")
```

As you can see in the help page `?cat` does not return anything (`null`). So the behavior is as documented.

Comment: Perfect! I knew I was doing something dumb.

Comment: What is the difference between `paste` and `paste0`?

Comment: @phroureo The separator. The `paste0`-function is equivalent to using `sep=""` whereas `paste` has `sep = " "` as default separator.

Comment: `paste0` is just `paste` with `sep=""`.

Comment: @BingSun I thought so too, but from the documentation, they are actually only equivalent. The `paste0` is apparently more efficient. Anyway, potato potato.

Comment: @phroureo Glad I could help, and not dumb at all. It is a easy mistake to make if you're not familiar with the language.